# Magento Navigation like Zalando

Tags: module, magento

Does anybody know if there is a module for Magento for the navigation like Zalando nl has it. They make a separation in Home, Women, Men, Children and when you click at men you have the second layer of navigation in a line under the three main categories. Would you say that we should do this with seperate stores (men, women, children) or with one root category with and then seperate it in to three main categories with subcategories.

Let me know if you know such a module.

Thanks